# AVPlayer cannot assign value of type to type

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayer, avplayeritem

I recently upgraded my code to swift 3, and I have 2 errors that relate to the AVPlayer in my app.

EDIT: Here are the declarations:

```
public var avPlayer = AVPlayer()
public var avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem?.self
```

Here's the function I'm referencing:

```
func stream() {
    let urlString = streamURLForSong
    let urlItem = URL(string: urlString)
    avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: urlItem!) // ERROR: Cannot assign value of type 'AVPlayerItem' to type 'AVPlayerItem?.Type?'
    avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: avPlayerItem!) // ERROR: Cannot convert value of type 'AVPlayerItem?.Type' (aka 'Optional<AVPlayerItem>.Type') to expected argument 'AVPlayerItem?'
}
```

This worked before, but after upgrading to Swift 3 using Xcode, the errors commented above are shown.

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we see your declaration of `avPlayerItem`?

Comment: Please show `avPlayerItem` and `avPlayer` declaration.

Comment: public var avPlayer = AVPlayer()
public var avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem?.self

Comment: "This worked before" No, it never did. It was _never_ correct to say `avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem?.self`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this function to compile with slight modification in an Xcode playground. My version looked like this:

```
import AVFoundation

func stream() {  
    let urlString = "http://google.com"
    let urlItem = URL(string: urlString)
    let avPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem? = AVPlayerItem(url: urlItem!) // ERROR: Cannot assign value of type 'AVPlayerItem' to type 'AVPlayerItem?.Type?'
    let avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: avPlayerItem) // ERROR: Cannot convert value of type 'AVPlayerItem?.Type' (aka 'Optional<AVPlayerItem>.Type') to expected argument 'AVPlayerItem?'
}
```

I made urlString a dummy address, and also changed the last line so that we don't force unwrap your `AVPlayerItem` when passing it to `AVPlayer`.

**Edit:**

If you're trying to tell Swift what data type to use for `avPlayerItem`, you want to use this syntax:

```
public var avPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem
```

What you've done is assign the class itself as the contents of the `avPlayerItem` variable, so the data type is actually `AVPlayerItem?.Type?` instead of `AVPlayerItem?`.

Answer (score 2):

This code is wrong:

```
public var avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem?.self
```

Delete `.self`. That code makes this a *type* whereas you want an *instance* to go here. Now delete `=` and use `:` instead, to declare the type.

To give a simpler example, this code is illegal:

```
var x = String?.self
x = "howdy" // compile error
```

This is what is needed:

```
var x : String?
x = "howdy"
```